# Let $A$ be a $4\times 4$ matrix such that: $r(A+I)=3$ and $r(A-3I)=2$, then which of these is true?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

a) $A$ has $0$ as an eigenvalue.
b) $A$ is not diagonalizable.
c) $A$ has at least $3$ different eigenvalues. 
d) $A$ has at least $3$ eigen vectors that are linearly independent. 
e) we can't infer any of (a-d) about $A$.

*My Attempt* : 
$r(A+I)=3$, $(A+I)$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix, with a rank of $3$ then it's not invertible and $det(A+I)=0$, which means $-1$ is an eigen value of $A$ with geometric multiplicity of $n-r(A+I)=4-3=1$. 

Same way with $r(A-3I)$, and got that $|A-3I|=0$, which means $3$ is an eigen value with geometric multiplicity of $2$. 

So I looked back and said (a) isn't true since $0$ isn't necessary the last eigenvalue. and couldn't infer any more information so I went with (e) as an answer, but the answer was (d). 
Would appreciate it if someone can point out my mistakes or what I have missed and led me to the wrong answer, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $R$ and $r$?

Comment: @DiegoMath whoops they're all ranks I'll edit them now.

Comment: You're told that the answer is (d). Now that you know that this is the answer, can you see why it's true? You're actually quite close with your eigenvalue analysis already.

Comment: Hint: the geometric multiplicity is the dimension of the eingenspace. Now, you can justify the correct answer?

Comment: Of course, to disprove b) and c), which you now know are false, the easiest way is to produce a matrix which breaks them. (Make one matrix for each of them; that's much easier than finding a single matrix that counters both at the same time, which I think is impossible.)

Comment: Appreciate all the help thanks to all of you, can't believe I missed about the dimension of the eigenspace, that means i have a dimension of 3 and theyre all linearly independent, guess now i wont forget it again!

Answer (score 0):

To disprove $(a)$ and $(b)$ consider
$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & & & \\ & 3 & & \\ & & 3 & \\ & & & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
and to disprove $(c)$ consider
$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & & & \\ & 3 & 1 & \\ & & 3 & \\ & & & 3\end{bmatrix}.$$